# I can't seem to understand loops

Tags: loops, python-2.7

Yes I'm new to this and I'm having a very hard time learning. This has me very confused. I have tried for hours to create a loop where if the value of a variable is not what it should be, it will continue asking for raw_input until it is what it should be and the program moves to the next function, as well as display something like "Try again" It's probably simple but I can't figure it out. I'm talking about the code after first_action = raw_input(">> ")

```
def start():
    print """You awaken in a strange lanscape, You are on a steep hillside 
    surrounded by trees, and you can see large mountains in the distance."""
    print "....."
    print "....."
    print "You struggle to regain your senses, and you realize you don't know who you are, or how you got here."
    print "You have the following items: %s" % i
    print "It's dark, perhaps you should sleep until the sun rises."
    print "What do you do?"

def cryptic_message(read):
    print read, "A paper with a message written in a strange language."

def day_1():
    print "_-_-_Dream_-_-_"
    print "It is relativity. It is a concept you know as time."
    print """This time, what is it? You ask "me" and I do not know. Ask yourself."""
    print """It is illusion. Oh look, "time" to wake up!"""
    print "....."
    print "....."
    print "You awaken, dazed and tired"
    print "What do you do?"

def knife(cut, stab):
    print "What do you want to do with the knife?"
    knife = raw_input(">> ")

def photo(view):
    print "A faded photo of a man on a park bench"

i = ['clothing','small knife','strange photo','cryptic message']

start()
first_action = raw_input(">> ")
first_action == False
while first_action is False:
    if first_action == "sleep":
        print "You lay on the grass for a hardly restful sleep."
        first_action == True
        day_1()
    elif first_action == "do nothing":
        print "Try again"
        first_action == False
    else: "Try again"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
inp = ''
desired = 'hello'
while inp != desired:
    inp = raw_input('Enter a greeting: ')
```

This will continue to ask for input until `inp` is `desired`:

```
>>> inp = ''
>>> desired = 'hello'
>>> while inp != desired:
...     inp = raw_input('Enter a greeting: ')
... 
Enter a greeting: bye
Enter a greeting: no
Enter a greeting: what's up
Enter a greeting: hello
>>>
```

In your code:

```
first_action = raw_input(">> ")

while first_action != "False::
    print "Try again"
    first_action = raw_input(">> ")
print "You lay on the grass for a hardly restful sleep."
day_1()
```